# ASP MVC 4 Data passing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im a new ASP MVC learner, Im working on a small pieces and getting stuck. The scenario is that user is creating new account in which accountID is automatically created by SQL. I want to pass this ID to the next step, let user input name and address. How would I pass this ID or any solution for this scenario? Think about passing data by TempData or Session but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think account name is unique too, so after insert, I would select by account name to get the id.

Comment: When you need the data to be persisted across different request use `Session` if it is only between one consecutive request use  TempData

Answer (score 0):

`TempData` will save the data until the end of your subsequent request.

There is also `ViewBag`/`ViewData`, which are really the same dictionary, are shorter lasting and they last only until the end of the current request.

`Session` lasts for as long as the user's session is open.

I believe `TempData` fits your bill, if "next step" means passing the data to a subsequent view, but if you need the data to be more durable, `Session` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same process you would use for your login form. If the user is already entered in the database, you might as well treat them as a logged-in user that does not have a fully filled profile, yet.

In ASP.NET MVC, this would - in a lot of cases - be solved by setting the Forms Authentication cookie to the newly registered username

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(newUser.Logon, false);
```

I think that storing the user id in `TempData` or `Session` is the wrong scope for that. For all normal purposes, a user that just registered to your website can be treated as logged in after the record has been inserted in the user database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are approaching this incorrectly.  You should have the user fill out all the information first, and then do all the registration, including creating the user and storing the data from the various steps all at the end.

If you do things the way you suggest, you will end up with partially registered users.  They will create an account, and then maybe close their browser and never finish the rest.  You will now have to write extra code to check all this every time they log in.

It's better to simply have your registration process do this all at once as an all or nothing process.

Comment: I think you're right, however my account login and account bio are separate tables in database. By you mean, first I have to combine two models into 1 view then writing a temp code which store all informations. After user finish the form, queries are going to be used to write to database?

Comment: @new-learner - It doesn't matter how many tables you have.  You can update 1000 tables if you want.  You don't have to save the data from one page to the next in a database.  You can have several options, such as posting the data to the next page, using Ajax to do the process and keep all your data in the parent page, etc.. lots of options..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way - 
Create the user (username and password will be the values from your form):

```
 WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username, password);
```

And then do this:

```
 int userID = 0;
 userID = WebSecurity.GetUserId(username);
```

Hope that helps.